# Real projective space and $n$-sphere

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-spaces

I know that $$\mathbb{R}^n\mathbb{P}\cong \mathbb{S}^n/{\pm 1}$$
Is there another equivalence relation apart from treating antipodal points as the same which we can quotient out from $\mathbb{S}^n$ to get another interesting space?

Comment: You can take any finite subgroup $H$ of $\operatorname{GL}(n+1,\mathbb R),$ which acts on $\mathbb S^n.$ Then $x\sim y$ for $x,y\in S^n$ if there is a $h\in H$ and a nonzero $\lambda$ so that $hx = \lambda y.$ Not sure what you get with that space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get lens spaces by quotienting out by actions of cyclic groups on odd-dimensional spheres (I never know if the term "lens space" is reserved for $S^3$ or if other odd-dimensional spheres count too)

Note that the antipodal action is the *only* nontrivial free action on even-dimensional spheres

Answer (score 1):

One that I can think of is to quotient along a circle of the sphere, which should yield $S^n/S^{1} \simeq S^{n-1} \wedge S^{n-1}$

Comment: $S^m \wedge S^m \approx S^{2m}$.

Comment: The OP means the wedge sum, not the smash product.